# php-mysql images link insert in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am totally new in PHP and MySQL. I have a product table which has `id, name, price, description, product_images` which is used to show product images.

I want to save my product image files in a folder and save that source path in the field `product_images`. Any tutorial or example please to insert data and retrieve in form.

Thanks

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql_4.htm Third link in google by "php file mysql insert"

Comment: First off: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Please take some time [reading the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): Your question is off-topic, and will be closed/deleted in no time. Check the help centre and tour to find out why

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution Chowdhury Sahib. This is Demo answer, because you do not show us your code so i write an answer as demo, so you see and understand what happen in code

First of all you make a form and in form a file type input:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="frm_images" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="upload_file" />
</form>
```

You must write this attribute in form tag, when ever you want to upload any file or image etc  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Now in process.php:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Password");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"Your DB Name");

    if(isset($_POST['upload_file'])){
        $file_name = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], "Your Folder Name/" . $file_name);

        $insertImage = "Insert Into table_name(field_name) Value('$file_name')";
        mysqli_query($con, $insertImage);
    }
?>
```

Hope you find your solution.